# Entity Framework stored procedure function imports with associated database object

Tags: .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, edmx

Let's say that in SQL, I have two tables:

[image]

In my EDMX,, I have a function import for a SPROC which returns columns corresponding the entity type for Table A.

If in the the SPROC, I select the corresponding data from Table B, will Entity Framework (4.1) know to associate that data without doing a lazy fetch to the database later on, when I request A.B.Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function import in .NET 4.0 can select data only from single table. You need two separate stored procedures to load both principal and dependent entities. Multiple result sets in EF 4.0 were supported only through [some extensions](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions).

.NET 4.5 also [supports stored procedures with multiple result sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402) but at least in VS 2012 RTM this feature wasn't supported in the designer (you had to do it manually in EDMX's XML). I didn't try yet if it is fixed in VS 2012 November Update.

Once you have stored procedure(s) returning result set for both principal and dependent table, EF will ensure that relations are correctly set up and you can always turn off lazy loading to make sure that there are no additional queries to the database.